# online retail data time series model using R

Tags: time-series, arima

I am new to time-series modeling. I have to create a time-series from the data found at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail. I have figured out how to aggregate the data, so now I have the data in following format with total revenue for each day. What would be best way to construct time series using R function ts() from this to forecast monthly or daily sales?

[image: Total revenue each day]

Comment: Given the revision, this seems a better fit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Usually what is done with transaction data is indeed *aggregating.*

1. **Define your target and time horizons**: What do you want predict exactly? Sales of the next day given all previous days? Sales of the next month given only the previous 12 months? Sales at each hour of the day?
2. **Build an aggregated dataset**: Aggregate sales for each day or month or other timespan depending on what you decided earlier.
3. **Apply suitable model**: Depending on *how* you aggregate the data it can be fed to a ARIMA (e.g. if you make it such that 1 record = 1 day) directly or into a linear regression (e.g. if 1 record = aggregation of previous $N$ days) or other models.

Comment: The prediction I am trying to make is sales for next month. I aggregated the data as sales for each day. So, the new data has the dates in one column in the format 2012-12-01 and total sales for that day in another column say 50000.50. How do I construct a time series from this using ts() to apply models?